# C++ Curl post dynamic var

Tags: c++, curl, post

I would like to use dynamic variables with POST curl
I use this code:

```
int send(const char*s)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;


  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/query.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=" + s);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  std::cout << std::endl << "Query sent" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And i get this error:

```
test.cpp:199:57: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [3]’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator+’
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=" + s);
                                                    ~~~~~^~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate `"q="` and `s` by yourself, there is no operator `+` in Cpp which concatenates chars array with pointer to chars. Create string with `"q="`, add data pointed by `s` to this string and call `c_str()` to get `const char*` pointer as parameter of *curl_easy_setopt* function:

```
#include <string>
....
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/query.php");
std::string buf("q=");
buf += s;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buf.c_str());
```

Comment: And note that `buf` MUST remain valid in memory and unmodified until `curl_easy_perform()` is done using the `char*` pointer you pass to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  Otherwise, you have to use [`CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks @rafix07 !!